# Odd choice of architecture by numpy.distutils

Tags: python, numpy, distutils

I'm trying to create a Python package with some C code and NumPy dependency, and I thought using `numpy.distutils` would be the simplest way to achieve that. So far I have `setup.py` file

```
from numpy.distutils.core import setup
from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
from distutils.extension import Extension

ext_modules=[
    Extension("test",
              sources=["test.c"],
              libraries=["gmp"],
    )
]

configuration = Configuration(
    package_name = "test",
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
)

setup(**configuration.todict())
```

and empty `test.c` in the same directory.

But for some reason, it adds awkward `-arch i386 -arch x86_64` flags during compilation (the system is Mac OS X), which leads to

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libgmp.dylib, 
file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386):  
/usr/local/lib/libgmp.dylib
```

warning and further problems in invoking C functions.

How do I fix that behavior? Can I specify the target architecture somehow?

**UPD**. Currently I just do

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" python setup.py build_ext  --inplace
```

But I'd like it to work on any platform without a priori knowledge of architecture, so that I could deploy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe these are added by `numpy.distutils` but `distutils` itself. `distutils` gets these flags from how Python was built, which in your case, was built as a fat binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. This information is obtained from the `$PREFIX/lib/python<version>/config/Makefile` file.

This is a pretty normal thing for people building packages with binary dependencies to have to deal with. You don't know whether their Python was built fat or thin, nor do you know how they built their `libgmp.dylib`. With a lot of effort, you could write some code in your `setup.py` that locates the `libgmp.dylib`, interrogates it for its architecture, then configures `distutils` to only use the right flags (and still correctly operate when this isn't necessary, fail gracefully, etc.). But you probably get more bang for your development effort by simply documenting that this may come up and the `ARCHFLAGS=` solution.

Comment: Well... it seems to have no other options indeed.